# Unified explanation for parametrization independence

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry

Let $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be a $C^1$ curve. We have the following different kinds of line integrals:

(i) $\displaystyle\int_a^bf(\gamma(t))|\gamma'(t)|dt$ where $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a scalar field;

(ii) $\displaystyle\int_a^bF(\gamma(t))\cdot\gamma'(t)dt$ where $F:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector field;

(iii) $\displaystyle\int_a^bf(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt$ where $n=2$ and $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is a complex function (identify $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$).

These are all parametrization independent, in the sense that if we replace $\gamma$ by $\eta=\gamma\circ\alpha$, where $\alpha:[c,d]\rightarrow[a,b]$ is a $C^1$ increasing diffeomorphism, then the integral does not change. I wonder if there is some "high-tech" way to explain them all at once.

My attempt: both the dot product $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and complex multiplication $\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ are bi-linear. I feel like the following general form is true. If $B:\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$ is a bi-linear map, then $\displaystyle\int_a^bB(f(\gamma(t)),\gamma'(t))dt$ is parametrization independent for $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$; <s>actually if $G:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^k)$ is continuous, then $\displaystyle\int_a^bG(t)(\gamma'(t))dt$ is parametrization independent</s>. If this works then it unifies (ii) and (iii), but I don't see how to also cover (i). Could this be explained using differential form and density (I am still trying to understand their definitions)? Are there generalizations to higher dimensions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\phi : \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ be continuous with the property
$$\phi(x,\lambda y)  = \lambda \phi(x,y) \text{ for all } x, y \in \mathbb R^n \text{ and all } \lambda > 0 \tag{1}.$$
All of your integrals have the form
$$\int_a^b \phi(\gamma(t),\gamma'(t)) dt \in \mathbb R^m \tag{2}. $$
In case (i) we have $\phi(x,y) = f(x)\lvert y \rvert$, in case (ii)  $\phi(x,y) = F(x)\cdot y $ and in case (iii) $\phi(x,y) = f(x)y$ (here we use complex multiplication on $\mathbb R^2 = \mathbb C$).

The integrals $(2)$ are of course defined componentwise, i.e. the $i$-th coordinate of $\int_a^b \phi(\gamma(t),\gamma'(t)) dt$ is given as
$$\int_a^b \phi_i(\gamma(t),\gamma'(t)) dt$$
where $\phi_i : \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R$ is the $i$-th coordinate function of $\phi$. Therefore the case $m > 1$ is covered by the case $m = 1$.

Recall that for $\mathbb R^2 =  \mathbb C$ the coordinate functions of $\phi$ are denoted as $\Re(\phi)$ and $\Im(\phi)$, thus
$$\int_a^b \phi(\gamma(t),\gamma'(t)) dt = \int_a^b \Re(\phi(\gamma(t),\gamma'(t))) dt + i \int_a^b \Im(\phi(\gamma(t),\gamma'(t))) dt  .$$

So let us consider  $\phi : \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$. If we replace $\gamma$ by $η=γ∘α$, then integration by substitution gives
$$\int_a^b \phi(\gamma(t),\gamma'(t)) dt = \int_c^d \phi(\gamma(\alpha(s)),\gamma'(\alpha(s)))\alpha'(s) ds .$$
But $\alpha'(s) > 0$ because $\alpha$ is an increasing diffeomorphism, thus
$$\int_a^b \phi(\gamma(t),\gamma'(t)) dt = \int_c^d \phi(\gamma(\alpha(s)),\alpha'(s)\gamma'(\alpha(s))) ds = \int_c^d \phi((\gamma \circ \alpha)(s),(\gamma \circ \alpha)'(s)) ds .$$

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, too long for a comment:

I think case $(i)$ cannot be covered by this (nice!) generalization, as it is clearly not linear with respect to $\gamma'$. I also feel like the $B$ construction would be parametrization independent but I **do not think** that the $G$ construction would be, as it **explicitly** depends on $t$.

In the lenguage of differential forms $|\gamma'|dt$ corresponds to restricting the ambient measure of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to the curve, under the specific parametrization. And indeed there are generalizations, leading to the theory of *integration of manifolds*.

Note that $(i)$ does not depend on the orientation of the curve (you might as well use $\gamma(-t)$, while $(ii)$ and $(iii)$ **do** depend on the orientation!

Comment: I know the Stoke's Theorem stated in terms of differential form, but I don't know how to translate it to more down-to-earth language, like line integral of scalar field or vector field. Is it accurate to say that differential form corresponds to vector field while density corresponds to scalar field?